# Finish with simulated annealing search

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I did my best to solve the task, but the code fails.
My code is located here:[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/nikolayresh/Simulated-Annealing-Search)
The sense of this task is that initially you have a sequence: **[B1, B2, B3, B4, 0, W1, W2, W3]** where B1, B2, B3, B4 - black balls on the board, 0 - gap on the board, W1, W2, W3 - white balls on the board. And the final state must be: **[W1, W2, W3, 0, B1, B2, B3, B4]**
Rules for the gap - the closest ball to gap can swap places with it OR the second closest ball can swap places with gap by jumping over the first closest ball.
For example, such states are valid: **[B1, B2, B3, 0, B4, W1, W2, W3]**,
**[B1, B2, 0, B4, B3, W1, W2, W3]** or **[B1, B2, B3, B4, W2, W1, 0, W3]**.
Black balls can only be moved to the right, white balls only to the left.
What function to use with simulated annealing to get to solution?

**What I have tried?**
Tried to build the optimizing function that calculates sum of squares of distances between goal state and each successive state, but the function is stuck.

Comment: This problem doesn't have any solution at all. You can easily show that with a simple DFS/BFS

Comment: Yep, thanks man! I understood it several hours ago, it's a task that goes to step-restricted problems (or dead-end problems) where each incorrect step will ruin solution. The best way to solve this is blind search. I tried with DFS and it worked well. But my university teacher is not qualified enough - I almost lost my mind for the last 3 days. Now I am calm :)